# Using Retrofit in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, retrofit2

I am trying to use `Retrofit2` library in my `libGDX` project. I have added the `gradle` dependencies and synced it in. However, `libGDX` uses `Java level 1.6` source compatibility by default which is quite a low version. Although this does not impact `Retrofit` directly, my concern is if it will be a problem during runtime. If yes, any better alternatives for this?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem for Android if you're targetting Android 2.3 or higher. I'm not sure about desktop versions though. Their doc claims you have to use Java 7 https://github.com/square/retrofit#download

Comment: Btw, it's absolutely fine. You can raise the target java version for desktop as well. There's nothing blocking.